# How to make first radio selected in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
$policyYear = 

Array
(
    [1] => 1 Year
    [2] => 2 Year
    [3] => 3 Year
)




<div>  
<?php
$options = $policyYear;
$attributes = array('legend' => false);
echo $this->Form->radio('policy_year', $options, $attributes);
?>
</div>
```

This is my code which is giving three radio button having values '1 Year', '2 Year' , '3 Year'.   But I want to set selected initially for value '1 Year'.  How can I do that ?.  I am new in cakephp. I know it in core php.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `$attributes` and add value

```
$attributes = array('legend' => false,'value' => $foo);
```